# Read/Modify PDF Metadata using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, metadata, itext, xmp

I am trying to use iTextSharp to read/modify PDF metadata. I figured out how to do it using pdfreader and pdfstamper.  I was wondering if I could also read/modify additional metadata information like copyright information and few others within the XMP photoshop namespace.

I would greatly appreciate any pointers to the solution.

Thank you,
Murugesh.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can read metadata using `PdfReader'.  I've read metadata like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("HelloWorldNoMetadata.pdf");
string s = reader.Info["Author"];
```

You can try the `iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.XmpWriter` class to write metadata.  I've never done it but [I found this code](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.pdf/2005-10/msg00245.html) below:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("HelloWorldNoMetadata.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,
 new FileOutputStream("HelloWorldStampedMetadata.pdf"));
HashMap info = reader.getInfo();
info.put("Author", "Bruno Lowagie");
info.put("Title", "Hello World stamped");
stamper.setMoreInfo(info);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
XmpWriter xmp = new XmpWriter(baos, info);
xmp.close();
stamper.setXmpMetadata(baos.toByteArray());
stamper.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works. I am able to put values to any schema within XMP now. But whenever I insert a value other than the common metadata fields (Author, Title, Subject, Keywords) it adds them as a custom field which goes under "pdfx" schema in addition to the schema where I am inserting it. I don't want them to be added as custom fields. Any pointers?

Thanks,
Murugesh.

Comment: @muruge - No sorry I don't have any pointers; I've never tried what you're doing.  I also couldn't find much on the iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp namespace.

Comment: Hi, Has anyone got a basic C# example of adding MetaData? I cant seem yto convert this to C#.Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Try the examples in the [iTextSharp book](https://itextpdf.com/en/book) there are examples on modifying any part of the pdf file!

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I am already done with this application. But hopefully this will help someone who is looking for an answer to this question.

Comment: Link dead. To be expected after 11 years. That's why there are rules about link only answers

Comment: Thanks for the update @Gerhard, appreciate your effort.