# Extract Data from .PDF files

Tags: c#, ssis

I need to extract data from .PDF files and load it in to SQL 2008.
Can any one tell me how to proceed??

Comment: What *data* contain those PDF files that you want to extract?

Comment: Info related to books(basically a list of best seller books in the market)

Comment: I think you mean metadata, which is the title and author and such

Comment: @Edootjuh I don't think he means metadata about the file - it sounds more like he wants to extract the contents of the file, which consists of a table of data, right S?

Comment: the file contains book info like title author price etc....i want to extract that info from the PDF file

Answer (score 30):

Here is an example of how to use iTextSharp to extract text data from a PDF.  You'll have to fiddle with it some to make it do exactly what you want, I think it's a good outline.  You can see how the StringBuilder is being used to store the text, but you could easily change that to use SQL.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"c:\test.pdf");

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int x = 1; x <= reader.NumberOfPages; x++)
        {
            PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(x);
            IRenderListener listener = new SBTextRenderer(builder);
            PdfContentStreamProcessor processor = new PdfContentStreamProcessor(listener);
            PdfDictionary pageDic = reader.GetPageN(x);
            PdfDictionary resourcesDic = pageDic.GetAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
            processor.ProcessContent(ContentByteUtils.GetContentBytesForPage(reader, x), resourcesDic);
        }
    }

public class SBTextRenderer : IRenderListener
{

    private StringBuilder _builder;
    public SBTextRenderer(StringBuilder builder)
    {
        _builder = builder;
    }
    #region IRenderListener Members

    public void BeginTextBlock()
    {
    }

    public void EndTextBlock()
    {
    }

    public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
    }

    public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        _builder.Append(renderInfo.GetText());
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Imagine if you asked this question. How can I load data from *arbitrary* text files into a SQL table. The challenge isn't opening the text file and reading it, its getting meaningful data out of the files automatically.

So you can use either [iText](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) or [pdfSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/) to read the PDF files, but its the getting meaningful data out that's going to be the challenge.

Comment: More specifically, the C# implementation of iText iTextSharp :--> http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Comment: I tried ItextSharp but it did not work, basically almost all the functions in it are to create and edit a PDF doc but not to read the data.....could u provide me a sample example?

Answer (score 7):

what you need to do is to use a tool to extract the text from PDF first and then read the file into a binary reader .. then store it into your database .. for extracting the text there are several tools to use. the first to mention are:

[iTextsharp](http://www.itextsharp.com/) which is a Library that can be [downloaded](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) and  used to do extensive work and in-depth edits and builds when dealing with PDF documents, and there are a lot of examples available online along with a full book that explains the ins and outs of it

The second tool is [Adobe PDF iFilter](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=2611) which is a tool from adobe to deal with PDF modifications and manipulation.

Also [Foxit iFilter](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/ifilter/) also is a similar assembly that can do just what u r asking for!

[PDF Box](http://studentclub.ro/lucians_weblog/archive/2007/03/22/read-from-a-pdf-file-using-c.aspx)will also serve you!

these are the most well known and well documented ones!
check the following examples:
try the following examples on code project:

[Parsing PDF files in .NET using PDFBox and IKVM.NET.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/pdf2text.aspx)

[A simple class to extract plain text from PDF documents with ITextSharp](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/PDFToText.aspx)

[Using the IFilter interface to extract text from various document types](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IFilter.aspx)

[A parser for PDF Forms written in C#.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/mgpdfreader.aspx)
These do the job and they ain't hard to understand. Hope they help you :-)

**A final note:** as for me, i would iTextSharp as it's the most well documented library with most available examples.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean metadata, try this question (first answer)

[Read/Modify PDF Metadata using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761646/read-modify-pdf-metadata-using-itextsharp)

You'll have to do the database stuff yourself though.