# how to read pdf file and load it into sql server ( with pdf is image)

Tags: c#, pdf

I have found this for how to read normal pdf

[Extract Data from .PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784385/extract-data-from-pdf-files)

but my pdfs are scanned images.

how cna I read them in c# asp.net?

Comment: Extract the images and use some sort of OCR to extract the text from the images

Comment: For example, using Microsoft's cloud services, you could use [Azure cognitive services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp-print-text) for the OCR part