# How to export data from the MS Access to PDF using Java?

Tags: java, ms-access, itext

Hi i need to access data from msaccess like author,version,keywords,pdf name and same update to  same pdf filea  using java code.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the way to do this is to connect to MS Access using jdbc. See here: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-09/03-qa-0922-access.html

Once you have a connection to the access database you will want to write some queries to pull out the information you need: http://www.heimetli.ch/jdbc/JDBCQuery.html

Next you'll need to create a report and export it to pdf. I recommend using JASPER reports (http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports).

If your not pretty decent with java, this could easily turn into a long process. There are several steps, pieces that you need to get to work together. Give your self some time to figure it out.

Comment: I believe Bala wants to update the PDF's metadata with information from an external source... in this case, some table(s) on an MS Access database.

Comment: @Dilum okay, upon re-reading the question I think I see what he's trying to get at. Your answer looks good.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to update a PDF's metadata. And you want the input to be from MS Access. I have not used itext, but perhaps this post for the C# equivalent will help with the part where you modify PDFs:  [Read/Modify PDF Metadata using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761646/read-modify-pdf-metadata-using-itextsharp)